# Open-source wysiwyg embedded html editor

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, content-management-system, wysiwyg

I'm developing my own simple CMS. Now I imagined the process of creating a new page where after creating the said page the system will load the newly created page with entire layout already rendered with few `div` having the attribute `contenteditable="true"`.

This allows user to click in this `div` add/change some content and then when user will press some Save Page button I can use JS to pull all innerHTML from those editable divs and update the page content in my DB.

Now I could go the very long way using jquery-ui and implement drag/drop/clickable feature and when user clicks on a div I could load Bootstrap WYSIWYG editor in to it to help user format the content.

I'm not looking to resell this but I want to have it done properly. I found a superb JS Lib http://createjs.org/ However I cannot get it to work the toolbar simply wont load.

I don't need any special functionality simply ability to click on a div and being able to add content or change it's content.

Any library suggestion or tips how to go about this.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/). I haven't used it but read about it yesterday and I think I will give it a go for one of my other projects.